# Unable to catch data

Tags: php, ajax, html-table, textbox

I am passing data using J-Query and AJAX to res.php page:-

**attempt.php** (my main page from where the res.php is called)

```
$.ajax(
                    {

                        url: "res.php", 
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data,     
                        success: function (data) 
                        {
                            var build_id='build_';
                            build_id += i;
                            alert(build_id);
                            $('#npc').append(data);
                            $('#build_id').attr('disabled','true');
                            var total = $("#build_id");
                            alert(total);
                        }
                    });
```

In the res.php page I am using the passed data to generate the query and retrieve data from the database and calculated the total value and display the total in a text box.

**res.php**

```
$i = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['i']);

$query = "select * from ";
$query = $query . $building;
$query = $query . " where lvl=" . $level;
$query = $query . ";";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error in Child Table!');
echo $i;
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$total_res = $data['lumber'] + $data['clay'] + $data['iron'] + $data['crop'];
echo '<tr><td>'. $building. '</td><td>'. $level. '</td><td><input type="text" style="width:70px" id="build_' . $i . '" value="' . $total_res . '"></td></tr>';
}
```

I am using `id="build_' . $i . '"` to auto increment the id of the text box. Till here everything goes fine.

Back to the attampt.php page,
when I try to access the data from the text box i am unable to access it.

The code that I'm using to access the data is:-

```
                            var build_id='build_';
                            build_id += i;
                            $('#build_id').attr('disabled','true');
                            var total = $("#build_id");
                            alert(total);
```

the alert function at the end of the code gives the following output:-

```
[object Object]
```

I am trying to append a list of text boxes with some values to a table and then calculate the sum of all the values in the text boxes. 
Please help.

Comment: Don't use the mysql_XXX functions, they're deprecated. Please switch to mysqli_XXX or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#build_id')` should be `$('#'+build_id)` and to calculate the total of all the values, you should put `var total=0;` outside your callback function, and the function should contain

```
total += $('#'+build_id).val();
```

Another problem is that each row of the table has the same `id="build_$i"`, but IDs have to be unique.

And do you really intend to display `$i` at the beginning of the table, without it being in a table row?

Comment: if you check the jquery code then I'm incrementing the value of `i` before sending it to the res.php page. So every time the values of `i` is different. And no that `i` is not to be displayed.. i am using it for finding out my errors at this moment.

Comment: But res.php has the loop `while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` which can print multiple rows, and they each use the same `$i` that it received as a parameter.

Comment: no it will not point multiple rows....that sql query will generate only one row..

Comment: You had me fooled. Why use a loop when there's only one row? Anyway, the first line of my answer is the important part. Did that solve it?

Comment: ` Why use a loop when there's only one row?` :D i keep thinking of changing it but always forget to...  and thanks it worked out.